# multiple input in a awk file

Tags: shell-script, awk

Please guide me to get out of it.
Thanks in advance.

I am having a situation that I have to write a awk script which takes the 
input of two .out files and generate a single .txt file.

```
$ cat file1.sh
awk -f awk_file.awk < outfile1.out outfile2.out  > text_file.txt
```

I want to display the .txt file like,

----------------Output from File1----------

```
column1 column2 column3
--------------------------------------------

columns i will pick from outfile1.out

columns i will pick from outfile1.out

--------------------------------------------
Total no. of columns from outfile1.out
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////
----------------Output from File2----------

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 column5
-------------------------------------------
columns i will pick from outfile2.out

columns i will pick from outfile2.out

columns i will pick from outfile2.out

columns i will pick from outfile2.out

----------------------------------------
Total no. of columns from outfile2.out
```

How resulting the text_file.txt???

Comment: And what is wrong with `awk -f awk_file.awk outfile1.out outfile2.out > text_file.txt`?

Comment: it will work but what should be inside the awk_file.awk file, or how to format the inputs of both the files or you can say how i will control the inputs of both the files...??

Comment: The content of `awk` script depends on what you are trying to do with those two files (`output1.out` and `output2.out`). So edit your question and add how resulting `text_file.txt` should look like.

Comment: can i mail the situation as i am not able to explain here??? @jimmij

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want. If you want to process files one after the other, you can simply call your awk script on both files sequentially with a loop, and redirect the output:

```
(for file in outfile1.out outfile2.out; do awk -f awk_file.awk < "$file"; done)  > text_file.txt
```

or in this case of two files, simply

```
(awk -f awk_file.awk < outfile1.out; awk -f awk_file.awk < outfile2.out) > text_file.txt
```

If you wanted to merge the files together before processing with awk (this will treat them as a single file), you just do

```
cat outfile1.out outfile2.out | awk -f awk_file.awk > text_file.txt
```

It's a nice practice to let a tool do one job well, and let the shell glue together the pieces into a functioning script.

Comment: can i mail the situation as i am not able to explain here??? @orion

Comment: Just modify your question to post a short (few lines) example of outfile1, outfile2 and what you expect as output. Right now the problem is we don't know what you are trying to do. If you just want to apply the same script to both files, then my answer above is ok. If you are merging or combining data, then you need something different.

Comment: yes i wanna get merging or combining data into single file

Comment: With what rule? Just tell us. A simple concatenation of two files is performed by `cat`. If you need something more sophisticated, you will probably need `getline` command in `awk`. But it really all depends on what you need, there are a lot of core utilities that are meant for different things, unless you tell us what you need, we can't help you.